# Can I use bash autocomplete when editing shell scripts in emacs?

Tags: bash, shell, emacs, autocomplete

In my environment, I have bash autocomplete set up to do lots of amazing things.
However, when I'm editing a shell script in emacs, all of that autocomplete magic goes away.

Is there any way to get emacs to do bash command line autocompletion when I'm editing shell scripts?

I would accept an answer that requires me to use a different editor, if that editor were available on Linux systems. I would also accept an answer that tells me that I need to use a different shell's autocomplete.

Comment: yes, you can use [bash-completion.el](https://github.com/szermatt/emacs-bash-completion)

Comment: As far as I can tell, that package is only for shell-mode (where I'm actually executing commands) and not for sh-mode (where I'm editing a shell script) which is what I need. I certainly can't get it to work in sh-mode, although it works in shell-mode.

Comment: it can be used in sh-mode as well with a little bit of elisp, I'll add an example config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[bash-completion.el](https://github.com/szermatt/emacs-bash-completion) provides an interface to normal bash completion, which can also be extended to work in normal `sh-mode`s with an addition to your `completion-at-point-functions`.  Here is how that could work, just using the command `sh-beginning-of-command` from `sh-script` to determine the current completion candidate (this could be extended to handle more complicated shell commands if necessary).

```
(require 'sh-script)                    ;sh-beginning-of-command
(require 'bash-completion)

(defun my-sh-completion-at-point ()
  (let ((end (point))
        (beg (save-excursion (sh-beginning-of-command))))
    (when (and beg (> end beg))
      (bash-completion-dynamic-complete-nocomint beg end t))))

(defun my-sh-hook ()
  (add-hook 'completion-at-point-functions #'my-sh-completion-at-point nil t))

(add-hook 'sh-mode-hook #'my-sh-hook)
```

Comment: If I may pester you just a little longer -- 

There seem to be two modes. Sometimes TAB does indentation while M-TAB does completion, and other times both TAB and M-TAB do completion and nothing does indentation. For example, the first time I edit a particular line, I need to use M-TAB for completion the first time, and then just TAB will do completion after that.

Is there a way to control this, or if not, can you help me understand it?

Comment: If you have `(setq tab-always-indent 'complete)` (which I would do), then `TAB` will try to indent first, and if the line is already indented it will do completion.  With this setting I peronally never use M-TAB, but see options for `tab-always-indent`

Comment: For me your solution does not work. If I try to complete something, like a filesystem path, i got "No match" in the echo area.